# Input using ng-model not binding when textbox is populated via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a text box that gets populated using javascript that is getting the data by reading a QR code and setting the value. I am using ng-model to bind to a variable in my controller which works fine when I type manually into the text box just not when it is populated with javascript. I am guessing there is some event I have to manually fire to trigger ng-model to do it's magic but I do not know what that event is or if it is even the right approach.
My input looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="read" name="itemId" class="form-control center-block" placeholder="Item Id" ng-model="scannedId"/>
```

I am setting the value with the following once the QR code reading javascript does it's thing and works:

```
$('#read').val(data);
```

I have tried the following to try and manually trigger an event I hoped ng-model would be listening for right after assigning val(data) but both fail:

```
$('#read').trigger('input');
and
angular.element($('#reader')).triggerHandler('onChange');
```

Everything works fine if I type in it manually just not when updated with javascript. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the model value inside of your controller. Don't use jQuery.

Inside of your controller, create an object:
`$scope.myModel = {};`

Then change your `ng-model="myModel.scannedId"`

Then inside of your controller, you can set the model `$scope.myModel.scannedId = data` and it will automatically bind.

Lesson being... Don't try to explicitly set 'value' with jQuery, especially if you have the `ngModel` directive on it. Somehow Angular overrides this, even when you can see the 'value' attribute has changed.

Comment: The code involved for reading a QR code is a third party library in which I pass in a function to set the value defined by ($('#read').val(data);). So unless I can somehow pass a controller method to the 3rd party js I would not be able to set the value in the controller. I was hoping I could fire some event on the input that would trigger ng-model to bind.

Comment: what's the 3rd party library?

Comment: I used this https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode and made some modifications to it. It is a wrapper around https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode to stream video on intervals.

Comment: What triggers calling the qrcode reader? Is it on file upload? Are you inserting an `<img>` tag into the `<div>` before calling it?

Comment: It samples the video camera on an interval and passes that img like in the sample of the html5-qrcode project. The input gets populated  just fine I think it just by passes some event that typing in the input triggers. I am updating the question to show my failed attempts at manually triggering events.

Comment: Take a look at this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/6bayLaFqZv58CqKKklbF?p=preview Basically, I created a directive that takes a 'callback' parameter. The 3rd party plugin is initialized on the qrcode directive and sends any data to that 'callback' function within your controller. Then the model is updated.

Comment: Btw... Make sure you allow your camera access. The demo should read 'foo bar'

Comment: I could not get your plunker to do anything but the code was enough to point me in the right direction and with a bunch of messing around with my code got it to work using a directive like you suggested. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

When you're outside from the AngularJS Environment you need to manual trigger the DigestCycle... So, try something like that:

```
var scope = $('#read').scope(); scope.apply(function() {scope.scannedId = 'new value outside AngularJS LifeCycle'; });
```

Comment: can you create a plunker for me?